# Unable to join two sub-queries

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table where I want to:
1) Check those visitors (VisitorID) who meet a requirement
2) Get all the times those visitor have come to my site.

I've been trying to do it joining my first query with all my conditions, and another query where I get the rest of the relevant variables.

```
SELECT ID, h.Info, h.Action
FROM `table` as A,
UNNEST (hits) as h
WHERE (h.Info LIKE '%PPP%' 
OR h.Info LIKE '%BBB%'
OR h.Info LIKE '%SSS%'
OR h.Info LIKE '%FFF%') AND  
h.Category LIKE '%Lock%' AND
(h.Action LIKE '%Regist%' OR h.Action LIKE '%NotR%') AND
h.Label LIKE '%Success%' 
JOIN
SELECT ID, h.Info, h.Action, time, visits, EXTRACT(TIME FROM TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(StartTime)) AS time_visit, PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", date) AS date_visit
FROM `table`,
UNNEST (hits) as h
WHERE (h.Info LIKE '%PPP%' 
OR h.Info LIKE '%BBB%'
OR h.Info LIKE '%SSS%'
OR h.Info LIKE '%FFF%') AND 
date > "20190529") AS B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

I've changed JOIN multiple times, included/excluded brackets, and I've run out of ideas.

Comment: why you marked your question with bigquery tag? accepted answer will not work with bq!

Comment: I used it and it worked, that's why I accepted it.

Comment: was it in bigquery? if so - it will produce error - for sure! anyway  - i was just curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will go on cte version

```
with cte as
(
SELECT ID, h.Info, h.Action
FROM `table` as A,
UNNEST (hits) as h
WHERE (h.Info LIKE '%PPP%' 
OR h.Info LIKE '%BBB%'
OR h.Info LIKE '%SSS%'
OR h.Info LIKE '%FFF%') AND  
h.Category LIKE '%Lock%' AND
(h.Action LIKE '%Regist%' OR h.Action LIKE '%NotR%') AND
h.Label LIKE '%Success%' 
),
cte1 as
(
SELECT ID, h.Info, h.Action, time, visits, EXTRACT(TIME FROM TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(StartTime)) AS time_visit, PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", date) AS date_visit
FROM `table`,
UNNEST (hits) as h
WHERE (h.Info LIKE '%PPP%' 
OR h.Info LIKE '%BBB%'
OR h.Info LIKE '%SSS%'
OR h.Info LIKE '%FFF%') AND 
date > "20190529"
) select cte.*,cte1.* from cte join cte1 on cte.id=cte1.id
```